# Toeplitz matrix in LaTeX

Tags: matrices

How do I create a Toeplitz matrix like the following in LaTeX?

[image: matrix]

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[ %\arraycolsep=4pt
 G = 
 \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
    1 \\
    2&1\\
   -1&2&1\\
     &-1&2&1\\
     &&-1&2&1\\
     &&&-1&2&1\\
     &&&&&&\ddots\\
     &&&&&&&\ddots\\
     &&&&&&&&\ddots\\
     &&&&&&&&&1
  \end{bmatrix*}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the last row must contain all non-zero elements: `-1 2 1`

Answer (score 8):

Here you go:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  G =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \cr
    2&1\cr
    -1&2&1\cr
    &-1&2&1\cr
    &&-1&2&1\cr
    &&&-1&2&1\cr
    &&&&&&\ddots\cr
    &&&&&&&\ddots\cr
    &&&&&&&&\ddots\cr
    &&&&&&&&&1\cr
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

To get nicer alignment of the minus-signs you could use an `array` with right-aligned columns

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  G =
  \left[
    \begin{array}{*{10}r}
      1 \cr
      2&1\cr
      -1&2&1\cr
      &-1&2&1\cr
      &&-1&2&1\cr
      &&&-1&2&1\cr
      &&&&&&\ddots\cr
      &&&&&&&\ddots\cr
      &&&&&&&&\ddots\cr
      &&&&&&&&&1\cr
    \end{array}
  \right]
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: to get the right alignment, it's simpler to load the `mathtools` package and write:  `begin{bmatrix*}[r] … \end{bmatrix*}`.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `\cr` instead of `\\`?

Comment: @Manuel Because I often use plain TeX and there is no ``\\``. In this case both are equivalent. Also `\cr` is primitive, hence it doesn't need to get expanded, you may save half a nano-second by that.

Answer (score 4):

Although late to the race my entry is presented below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin {document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0\\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & & & & \vdots\\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & \ddots & & & \vdots\\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & & \vdots\\
\vdots & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & \vdots\\
\vdots & & & \ddots & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0\\
\vdots & & & & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots  & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & -1 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico Sure, here is a reference http://www.ece.umn.edu/~mihailo/software/lqrsp/mass_spring.html

Comment: The matrix G is also referred to as a band matrix.

Comment: Your proposed solution produces a symmetric matrix, whereas the OP appears to want to produce an asymmetric matrix with all elements *above* the diagonal equal to zero.

Comment: @Mico My entry is final.

Comment: You can do whatever you want. An answer is usually considered to be more helpful, though, if it addresses the actual question that's been posed, rather than some other problem.

Comment: @Mico The original question asks for a Toeplitz matrix like the following. I contend that my submission is "like" the matrix in question. And I intend to share its code for future searches of Toeplitz matrices.

Comment: @Mico Furthermore, it is not at all clear that all entries above the diagonal should be zero. Why couldn't the superdiagonal be all 1's, and G still be a Toeplitz matrix?

Comment: @Mico you're policing the wrong entry Jabba.

Comment: Even if the unspecified elements of the matrix weren't equal to zero -- and you know full well that that's not the case -- your answer would still be incorrect.

Comment: @Mico Jabba the judge is too slow to strike the gavel. Why did you delete your comment asking if my G was Toeplitz? You're wasting this Jedi's time!

Answer (score 1):

With `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`. You need several compilations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{4pt}
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[columns-width=auto,xdots/shorten=6pt]
1 \\
2  & 1 \\
-1 & 2  & 1 \\
   & -1 & 2  & 1 \\
   &    & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
   &    &    & \Ddots[shorten-end=0pt] & \Ddots & \Ddots[draw-first] \\
\\
\\
   &    &    &   &   & & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]